# How can I animate a ggplot map graph according to year?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My df is (output2):

```
output2 <- data.frame(Country=c(Turkey, Italy, Spain, Turkey, Italy, Spain),
 Year=c(1990, 1990,1990,1991,1991,1991), 
 v2x_regime=c(0,1,1,1,0,0), 
 SupDem=c(0.9554,0.8685, 0.7849,0.9382,0.2839,0.39383))
```

```
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
class(world)

plotdata <- dplyr::left_join(world, filter(output2, Year == 2020), by = c("admin" = "Country"))

ggplot(data = plotdata) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = SupDem)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") +
  ggtitle("Democratic Support - 2020")
```

This only maps the value for 2020. I wanna see how it changes from the beginning of the data set to the end of it. For example from 1990 to 2020.

Comment: The objects `world`  and `output2` are  not defined. Could you update the question to make  it reproducible and include reference to the packages used?

Comment: Thank you peter, output2 and the df I shows are the same. I hope it is clear now

Comment: Would it automatically animate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `gganimate` which using `transition_states(Year)` allows to animate your maps over time.

Note: As your example includes only data for two years I used some fake random data which includes 6 years. Moreover, for the reprex I first added a background world map and included only the data for the three countries for the animated part of the map.

```r
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library(gganimate)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
world <- dplyr::select(world, admin, geometry)

plotdata <- dplyr::inner_join(world, output2, by = c("admin" = "Country"))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world, size = .1) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = SupDem), data = plotdata) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") +
  ggtitle("Democratic Support - {closest_state}") +
  transition_states(Year)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
output2 <- data.frame(
  Country = rep(c("Turkey", "Italy", "Spain"), each = 7),
  Year = rep(seq(1990, 2020, by = 5), 3),
  SupDem = sample(c(0.9554, 0.8685, 0.7849, 0.9382, 0.2839, 0.39383), 7 * 3, replace = TRUE)
)
```

Comment: I am having error: Error in transform_sf(all_frames, next_state, ease, params$transition_length[i],  : 
  The transformr package is required to tween sf layers

Comment: Yeah. I got the same error on the first run. (: `install.packages("transformr")` should solve it.

Comment: It works like a charm. One small obstacle is that when I save the gif, it appears very small. How can it be resized?

Comment: You could set the width and height and resolution using e.g. `anim_save("foo.gif", width = 6, height = 3, units = "in", res = 300)`

Comment: It does not change anything, so interesting:/

Comment: How could you share your animation with that size? Do you have whole code? It does not work somehow.